# Tensorflow DeepLab: Shape mismatch in tuple component 1. Expected [x,x,3], got [y,y,3]

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I' m trying to use the [deeplab3+](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/deeplab) tensorflow implementation to finetune with a new dataset (with a different number of classes). I converted the dataset to tfrecords and started to [train](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/train.py) the model without problems. Now I want to evaluate the new checkpoint, running the [evaluation](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/eval.py) script, and I obtain a shape mismatch error.

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Shape mismatch

The model implementation uses tensorflow.slim and I think my problem is related to the function

```
slim.evaluation.evaluation_loop(
    master=FLAGS.master,
    checkpoint_dir=FLAGS.checkpoint_dir,
    logdir=FLAGS.eval_logdir,
    num_evals=num_batches,
    eval_op=list(metrics_to_updates.values()),
    max_number_of_evaluations=num_eval_iters,
    eval_interval_secs=FLAGS.eval_interval_secs,
    hooks=[tf_debug.LocalCLIDebugHook()]))
```

The log of my error

```
`tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Shape mismatch in tuple component 1. Expected [513,513,3], got [2448,2448,3]
 [[Node: batch/padding_fifo_queue_enqueue = QueueEnqueueV2[Tcomponents=[DT_INT64, DT_FLOAT, DT_STRING, DT_INT32, DT_UINT8, DT_INT64], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](batch/padding_fifo_queue, Reshape_3/_4659, add_2/_4661, Reshape_1, add_3/_4663, case/cond/Merge/_4665, Reshape_6/_4667)]]`
```

I don't understand this error because the implementation uses the same [preprocessing](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/input_preprocess.py) routine during training and validation. I also tried to debug using tf_debug.LocalCLIDebugHook() but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Two solutions:

- Simply change `eval_crop_size`/`vis_crop_size` to max image size in your evaluation set.
- Resize your evaluation to have max image size length < 513 using `tf.image.resize_image_with_pad` (will not change aspect ratio) or `tf.image.resize_images` (will change aspect ratio but no padding)

Main reason behind is in [input_preprocess.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/input_preprocess.py). Below codes reveal how input are pre-processed to ensure size compatibility: images are padded (if they are smaller than crop_size), and then cropped **(FOR TRAINING ONLY)**.

```
# Pad image and label to have dimensions >= [crop_height, crop_width]
  image_shape = tf.shape(processed_image)
  image_height = image_shape[0]
  image_width = image_shape[1]

  target_height = image_height + tf.maximum(crop_height - image_height, 0)
  target_width = image_width + tf.maximum(crop_width - image_width, 0)
```

```
# Randomly crop the image and label
  if is_training and label is not None:
    processed_image, label = preprocess_utils.random_crop(
        [processed_image, label], crop_height, crop_width)
```

Answer (score 0):

It was posted on github as issue and solution was in this comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/3886#issuecomment-378996570

Copy-paste from there:

Set eval_crop_size = output_stride * k + 1 for your dataset.
The default value, 513, is set for PASCAL images whose largest image dimension is 512.
We pick k = 32, resulting in eval_crop_size = 16 * 32 + 1 = 513 > 512, since we will do whole image inference.
Similar case as we did for Cityscapes images, where we set eval_crop_size = 1025x2049.